# Mongoose : custom schema type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I followed this [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html) on custom schema type, to create a "large string":

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let STRING_LARGE = (key, options) => {   
  mongoose.SchemaType.call(this, key, options, 'STRING_LARGE'); 
}; 
STRING_LARGE.prototype = Object.create(mongoose.SchemaType.prototype);

STRING_LARGE.prototype.cast = function(val) {   
  let _val = String(val);   
  if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,400}$/.test(_val)){
    throw new Error('STRING_LARGE: ' + val + ' is not a valid STRING_LARGE');   
  }

  return _val; };

module.exports = STRING_LARGE;
```

And I use it like this in a schema:

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Schema.Types.STRING_LARGE = require('./types/string_large')

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  details:     { type: STRING_LARGE, required: true },
  link:        { type: STRING_LARGE, required: true }
});

module.exports = schema;
```

But I get the error :

> [path]\schemas[shema.js]:8
>   details: { type: STRING_LARGE, required: true },
>
> ReferenceError: STRING_LARGE is not defined
>   at Object. ([path]\schemas[shema.js]:8:24)
>   ...

**-------------------------- UPDATE : WORKING CODE --------------------------**

> use "function ()" instead of "() =>"

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

function STRING_LARGE (key, options) {   
  mongoose.SchemaType.call(this, key, options, 'STRING_LARGE'); 
}; 
STRING_LARGE.prototype = Object.create(mongoose.SchemaType.prototype);

STRING_LARGE.prototype.cast = function(val) {   
  let _val = String(val);   
  if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,400}$/.test(_val)){
    throw new Error('STRING_LARGE: ' + val + ' is not a valid STRING_LARGE');   
  }

  return _val; };
```

> use "mongoose.Schema.Types.LARGE_STRING" instead of "LARGE_STRING"

```
module.exports = STRING_LARGE;

"use strict";

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Schema.Types.STRING_LARGE = require('./types/string_large')

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  details:     { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.STRING_LARGE, required: true },
  link:        { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.STRING_LARGE, required: true }
});

module.exports = schema;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning your type to `mongoose.Schema.Types.STRING_LARGE` and then use `STRING_LARGE` - that's where your `ReferenceError` is thrown. You have to use your type directly:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  details:     { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.STRING_LARGE, required: true },
  link:        { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.STRING_LARGE, required: true }
});
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but I get another error, I edited my question if you want to take a look

Comment: In the type definition, you are using `this` in an arrow function - it's not going to work, as arrow functions preservers context. Change `let STRING_LARGE = (key, options) => {...}` to `function STRING_LARGE (key, options) {...}` - it should be fine.

Comment: seems to work! thx! I should be more careful when I am using arrow functions!